# From list of numbers to number in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm in Prolog and i have a list of numbers like :

```
L = [4,8,0]
```

I want to obtain the correspondent number 480.
But i didn't succeed.

What i tried is to convert every numeric element from L into its correspondent char code, using the built-in operator **char_code** and then use the built-in operator number_codes in order to obtain the numeric term from the list of char codes. However it doesn't work. Can you help me ?

```
test([],[]).
test([X|Y],[C|K]):-char_code(C,X),
    test(Y,K).

try(X):-
    test([4,8,0],L),
    number_codes(X,L).
```

ps: are you able to explain me why the combination **char_code -> number_codes** doesn't work ?

Comment: Check the documentation carefully on what `char_code/2` does and try some examples at the Prolog prompt. `char_code/2` gives the equivalence between a character and an ASCII code. A number is not a character. So what you get if you convert, say, 4 to a code, you get, `'\004'` which is just a character representation of the number 4, not the ASCII representation of a `'4'` (which is 52 decimal). Instead of `char_code(C,X)` try `atom_number(C, X).`

Comment: I don't think this is quite an exactly duplicate because the OP is asking why the use of `char_code/2` and `number_codes/2` as a solution doesn't work. This approach is not covered in the "duplicate" answer.

Answer (score 1):

The predicate `char_code` is a relation that defines the equivalence between a character and its ASCII code. For example, `char_code(a, 96)` is true since 96 is the decimal ASCII code for the character `'a'`. If you were, for example, to query, `char_code(C, 96)` you would get `C = a` as a solution. Similarly, `char_code('9', 57)` is true since 57 is the ASCII code for the *character* that that represents the number 9. Note that `'9'` here is not a numeric 9, but the character `'9'`.

In your code, you are applying the `char_code/2` predicate to a raw number. So `char_code(C, 9)` will succeed if `C` is the character code whose ASCII value is the number 9 (in this case, a horizontal tab). When you apply this and then attempt to use `number_codes/2` on the values, you don't get digits since you aren't providing the ASCII codes corresponding to the digits.

You could see this if you were to do a simple test on your `test/2` predicate at the Prolog prompt:

```
?- test([4,8,0], L).
L = ['\004\', '\b', '\000\']
```

What you expected was `L = ['4', '8', '0']`.

What you need to use is `atom_number/2` and not `char_code/2`. Then you have `atom_number(C, 9)` succeeding when `C = '9'` (`C` is bound to the *atom* `'9'`):

```
numbers_atoms([],[]).

numbers_atoms([X|Y],[C|K]) :-
    atom_number(C, X),
    numbers_atoms(Y,K).

digits_number(Digits, Number) :-
    numbers_atoms(Digits, Atoms),
    number_codes(Number, Atoms).
```

Then you get:

```
?- digits_number([4,8,0], Number).
Number = 480.
```

You can also write:

```
numbers_atoms(Numbers, Atoms) :-
    maplist(atom_number, Atoms, Numbers).
```

Comment: @Qwerto did I not answer your question properly?